# Navigating Map in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using `<map>` in html. I defined some area on the map. I created a separate pages for each area. I want to add something like  of any indication when hover the mouse at that area, is it possible to do.

```
<img src="images/Plan_ai-final.png" width="300px" height="450px" usemap="#planmap">
        <map name="planmap">
           <area shape="circle" coords="112,402,5" alt="View 1" href="view1.html">
           <area shape="circle" coords="247,350,5" alt="View 2" href="view2.html">
           <area shape="circle" coords="284,188,5" alt="View 3" href="view3.html">
           <area shape="circle" coords="272,42,5" alt="View 4" href="view4.html">
        </map>
```

Comment: Possibly, but without seeing your code it's nearly impossible to assist further.  Please post related portions of code to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Give id to every area : <area id="first"> etc. And add hover to that.  #first:hover { your changes}

Comment: i tried not working, but it working on another elements like <a> but it is behind the div

Answer (score 0):

Here you Can use Z-index attribute. And later you can provide id to every area and use same id's for hovering in CSS.